# Basic routing generates a 404 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, url-routing, mamp, laravel-routing

I'm trying to use the Laravel framework in building my application. However, I'm getting stuck with routing.

**Route**

```
Route::get('ecatalogs', 
    array('as' => 'ecatalog_latest', 'uses' => 'ecatalogs@latest'));
```

**Controller**

```
class Catalogs_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public $restful = true;

    public function get_latest()
    {
        return "wohoooooo!";
    }
}
```

My localhost files are stored in `/Users/ariefbayu/Sites/` and my Laravel application is stored in `/Users/ariefbayu/Sites/ecatalog/`. Inside this directory, I have an `info.php` file to confirm if my path settings are working, and they do. However, when I navigate to `http://localhost/ecatalog/public/index.php/ecatalogs` it always returns a 404 error. I know this is basic, but I don't know why this doesn't work.

FYI, I'm using a MAMP server, and I've set all source files' access permissions to `777` to test if this is a permission problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('ecatalogs', array('as'=>'ecatalog_latest', 'uses'=>'ecatalogs@latest'));
```

Notice the `ecatalogs@latest` pointer. This tells Laravel to call the `get_latest()` method on the `Ecatalog_Controller`.

And this is your controller `Catalogs_Controller` and function `get_latest()`. You need to call the `get_latest()` with this :

```
Route::get('ecatalogs', array('as'=>'ecatalog_latest', 'uses'=>'catalogs@latest'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying that you want to call the action "latest" inside the controller `ecatalogs`, but your controller is actually called `catalogs`. Change your uses parameter to `catalogs@latest` instead (or rename the file and class).